# Resampling based performance measure in caret

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, glmnet

I perform a penalized logistic regression and I train a model with *caret* (*glmnet*).

```r
model_fit <- train(Data[,-1], Data[,1],
               method = "glmnet",
               family="binomial",
               metric = "ROC",
               maximize="TRUE",
               trControl = ctrl,
               preProc = c("center", "scale"),
               tuneGrid=expand.grid(.alpha=0.5,.lambda=lambdaSeq)
               )
```

According to the *caret* documentation, the function `train` "[...] calculates a resampling based performance measure" and "Across each data set, the performance of held-out samples is calculated and the mean and standard deviation is summarized for each combination."

`results` is "A data frame" (containing) "the training error rate and values of the tuning parameters."

Is `model_fit$results$ROC` a vector (with size equal to the size of my tuning parameter `lambda`) of the mean of the performance measure across resampling? (And NOT the performance measure computed over the whole sample after re-estimating the model over the whole sample for each value of `lambda`?)

Comment: Consider looking at `model_fit$results`  it should be self-explanatory. Generally caret always shows performance measures obtained by re-sampling. To receive a more detailed answer I suggest you provide reproducible  code with an inbuilt data set and train control parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is `model_fit$results$ROC` a vector (with size equal to the size of my tuning parameter `lambda`) of the mean of the performance measure across resampling?

It is; to be precise, the length will be equal to the number of rows of your `tuneGrid`, which here it happens to coincide with the length of your `lambdaSeq` (since the only other parameter, `alpha`, is being held constant).

Here is a quick example, adapted from the [`caret` docs](https://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html) (it is with `gbm` and `Accuracy` metric, but the idea is the same):

```r
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)

set.seed(998)
inTraining <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class, p = .75, list = FALSE)
training <- Sonar[ inTraining,]
testing  <- Sonar[-inTraining,]

fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                           number = 5)

set.seed(825)

gbmGrid <-  expand.grid(interaction.depth = 3, 
                        n.trees = (1:3)*50, 
                        shrinkage = 0.1,
                        n.minobsinnode = 20)

gbmFit1 <- train(Class ~ ., data = training, 
                 method = "gbm", 
                 trControl = fitControl,
                 tuneGrid = gbmGrid,
                 ## This last option is actually one
                 ## for gbm() that passes through
                 verbose = FALSE)
```

Here, `gbmGrid` has 3 rows, i.e. it is consisted only of three (3) different values of `n.trees` with the other parameters held constant; hence, the corresponding `gbmFit1$results$Accuracy` will be a vector of length 3:

```r
gbmGrid
#   interaction.depth n.trees shrinkage n.minobsinnode
# 1                 3      50       0.1             20
# 2                 3     100       0.1             20
# 3                 3     150       0.1             20

gbmFit1$results
#   shrinkage interaction.depth n.minobsinnode n.trees  Accuracy     Kappa AccuracySD   KappaSD
# 1       0.1                 3             20      50 0.7450672 0.4862194 0.05960941 0.1160537
# 2       0.1                 3             20     100 0.7829704 0.5623801 0.05364031 0.1085451
# 3       0.1                 3             20     150 0.7765188 0.5498957 0.05263735 0.1061387

gbmFit1$results$Accuracy
# [1] 0.7450672 0.7829704 0.7765188
```

Each of the 3 `Accuracy` values returned is the result of the metric in the *validation* folds of the 5-fold cross validation we have used as a resampling technique; more precisely, it is the *mean* of the validation accuracies computed in these 5 folds (and you can see that there is an `AccuracySD` column, containing also its standard deviation).

> And NOT the performance measure computed over the whole sample after re-estimating the model over the whole sample for each value of lambda?

Correct, it is not that.